# ClientAbortException: java.net.SocketException: Connection reset error coming intermittently on jboss server

Tags: java, web-services, nginx, jboss

My web application connects to API to get data from database. Accessing page through browser sometime loads data correctly but sometime it throws connection reset exception. This happens intermittently.

First load doesn't work most of the times but refreshing/reloading page resolves issue temporarily.

My web page (UI) is deployed on Jboss server 6.4. There is an intermediate Load Balancer between my front end web application and backend APIs.

Jboss logs of web application -

```
ClientAbortException:  java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
at org.apache.catalina.connector.OutputBuffer.realWriteBytes(OutputBuffer.java:429)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.buf.ByteChunk.flushBuffer(ByteChunk.java:450)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.OutputBuffer.doFlush(OutputBuffer.java:368)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.OutputBuffer.flush(OutputBuffer.java:342)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteOutputStream.flush(CoyoteOutputStream.java:99)
at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.flush(BufferedOutputStream.java:141)
at java.io.FilterOutputStream.close(FilterOutputStream.java:158)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:734)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:847)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:295)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:214)
at org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.RuleChain.handleRewrite(RuleChain.java:176)
at org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.RuleChain.doRules(RuleChain.java:145)
at org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.UrlRewriter.processRequest(UrlRewriter.java:92)
at org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.UrlRewriteFilter.doFilter(UrlRewriteFilter.java:389)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:246)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:214)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:231)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:149)
at org.jboss.as.web.security.SubjectInfoSetupValve.invoke(SubjectInfoSetupValve.java:34)
at org.jboss.as.web.security.SecurityContextAssociationValve.invoke(SecurityContextAssociationValve.java:169)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:151)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:97)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:102)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:856)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:656)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:926)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Suppressed: ClientAbortException:  java.net.SocketException: Broken pipe (Write failed)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.OutputBuffer.realWriteBytes(OutputBuffer.java:429)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.buf.ByteChunk.flushBuffer(ByteChunk.java:450)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.OutputBuffer.doFlush(OutputBuffer.java:368)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.OutputBuffer.close(OutputBuffer.java:324)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteOutputStream.close(CoyoteOutputStream.java:106)
at java.io.FilterOutputStream.close(FilterOutputStream.java:159)
... 25 more
```

Piece of code which is calling API -

```
private String invokeGetTLS(String apiHost, HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException {
        System.out.println("Inside invokeGetTLS");
        URL apiURL = null;
        Map<String, List<String>> respHeaders = null;
        HttpsURLConnection apiURLConnection = null;
        try {
            apiURL = new URL(apiHost);
            apiURLConnection = (HttpsURLConnection) apiURL.openConnection();
            apiURLConnection.setDoInput(true);
            respHeaders = apiURLConnection.getHeaderFields();
            addResponseHeaders(respHeaders, response);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("Exception in invokeGetTLS  " + e.getMessage());
            e.printStackTrace();
            return e.getMessage();
        }
        try (BufferedInputStream inputBuffStream = new BufferedInputStream(apiURLConnection.getInputStream());
                BufferedOutputStream outBuffStream = new BufferedOutputStream(response.getOutputStream())) {
            int i;
            while ((i = ((InputStream) inputBuffStream).read()) >= 0) {
                outBuffStream.write(i);
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("Exception in invokeGetTLS  " + e.getMessage());
            e.printStackTrace();
            return e.getMessage();
        }
        System.out.println("Leaving invokeGetTLS");
        return null;
    }
```

We are using Nginx web server. Flow is like this - Nginx->serve/UI ->Load Balancer -> Api . I see below error on Nginx -

```
2019/09/19 11:32:32 [info] 12553#12553: *6 epoll_wait() reported that client prematurely closed connection, so upstream connection is closed too while reading response header from upstream
```

Answer (score 1):

```
ClientAbortException:  java.net.SocketException: Broken pipe
```

This means that the client closed the connection. If you have a load balancer acting as the client as you described, then the load balancer closed the connection too early. Tune your load balancer timeouts.

Comment: Thanks Kayaman. This didn't solve my issue. However, when it doesn't load, it displays error on nginx (attached above)